# Measuring IOPS for innodb_io_capacity

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

Aurimas Mikalauskas's [17 Key MySQL Config File Settings](http://www.speedemy.com/17-key-mysql-config-file-settings-mysql-5-7-proof/) gives the following advice regarding `innodb_io_capacity` and `innodb_io_capacity_max`:

> measure random write throughput of your storage and set innodb_io_capacity_max to the maximum you could achieve, and innodb_io_capacity to 50-75% of it, especially if your system is write-intensive.

But how do I measure these IOPS? What block size do I use (I assume the page size, so 16K by default)? Do I fsync after every block?

A fio command like this one gives me around 300 IOPS maximum, which seems very slow for these drives NVMe SSDs these are supposed to be. Most advice I can find online has these variables in the thousands.

```
fio --name fio --readwrite=randwrite --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --filename=fio --numjobs=1 --size=4G --gtod_reduce=1 --iodepth=64 --bs=16k --fsync=1
```

Comment: Great article on MySQL tuning/configuration - should be required reading before posting MySQL performance questions here = +1 - p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: @mozygipa      Ask Aurimas Mikalauskas to update his tips and point you to a measuring tool, From OS command prompt, iostat -xm 5 3  when the server is busy may give you a clue on current performance.  Bump innodb_io_capacity up 10%.  Remove innodb_io_capacity_max and the system will calculate innodb_io_capacity * 2 to set the max for you.

Comment: I think adding `--fsync` to the fio to measure IOs would impair the actual measurement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a running instance of mysql, throw some data at it, then compute

```
( Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written + 
       Innodb_dblwr_writes + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) / Uptime
```

Something like:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
run some heavy I/O queries
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

Tediously subtract the 5 values and evaluate the expression.

This will be a crude number, and you can probably set the innodb_io_capacity* higher than what the expression gives you.